# Why is the Sitecore keepalive task set to 1 hour by default?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, sitecore

The sitecore keepalive task set in web.config which calls a 'keepalive' url is configured to run every hour by default:

```
<agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.UrlAgent" method="Run" interval="01:00:00">
  <param desc="url">/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx</param>
  <LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
</agent>
```

If the default IIS application pool timeout is 20 minutes, does this not mean that the keepalive function will not work in its default configured state? i.e. a site left idle will invoke this task once at most, potentially keeping the site alive for a further 20 minutes whereupon it will timeout and unload until a real external request arrives.

Unless I'm missing something, this setting should be set to something under 20 minutes (or rather 20min minus the scheduler interval) to work as expected, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct that 1 hour is likely too high. By default the keep-alive agent does not work fully out of the box anyway. There are *typically* two things you need to do to ensure it works best:

1. Adjust the time to be more appropriate as you've mentioned. I like to do every 15 minutes personally: `interval="00:15:00"`
2. Adjust the path to be absolute to your site, not relative. By default, the path `/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx` will only make a request to your site if your site is configured in IIS to bind on `localhost`. The code in the UrlAgent assumes its requesting `http://localhost/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx`. 99% of the time you'd want to adjust this to be a public URL to your site, e.g. `http://www.mysite.com/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx`

Comment: There is some merit is allowing localhost to bind - using a public url in a load balanced setup can go a bit awry!

Answer (score 1):

[Sitecore UrlAgent Scheduler Task Module](http://nourestani.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/sitecore-urlagent-scheduler-task-module/)

The UrlAgent Scheduler Task Module is similar to the Sitecore built-in UrlAgent in web.config except that there is ability to define the Urls in Sitecore and ask Scheduler Task to execute them.

Mortaza Kamal Nourestani

Answer (score 0):

Default a Sitecore website will indeed not stay alive if this setting is not changed and your IIS is setup to recycle every 20 mins. We are not using the Sitecore agent, but have a module that requests a sitecore website every 15 minutes.